# MiKTeX installing: Should we change the words in the download page of Ubuntu?

Tags: miktex, installing

I note that there is a command `$(lsb_release -cs)` that outputs the version of current installed Ubuntu.

Therefore in the [download page](https://miktex.org/download#ubuntu)/unx/Ubuntu/Step-B we may change the three cases into a single command:

```bash
echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -cs)" universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list
```

I wonder why we do not use this code.

Comment: Who exactly is "we"?

Comment: @DG' Actually my major is mathematics, and in my major we always use 'we' for our opinion, if possible.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really comprehend, what you are asking. If you want the miktex website changed, write Christian Schenk directly: https://miktex.org/email

Comment: Got it. Thanks.